# How to package Shell Bash files for apt-get

Tags: raspbian, packages

Packaging a shell bash file and txt files for raspbian install using the apt-get install.

Is there a detailed and simple way of doing this.

to be able to package file so that they can be installed on outer pi using the apt-get install command

Comment: Hi. As of now I do not get what you want to accomplish. Maybe you'd like to add a little more to that question?

Comment: There's two different problems here: 1) packaging your files in a .deb file, which is pretty easy. 2) uploading the package to a repository which will be available to the second rpi, and there's no public repository that I know of.

Comment: Could you tell me how to package for .deb file then @MickaëlLeBaillif

Comment: I won't be able to give you enough details with only a short answer, so maybe the best for you would be to read some tutorials. See http://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository or http://askubuntu.com/questions/1345/what-is-the-simplest-debian-packaging-guide

Comment: Comoplimentary to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27920/how-do-i-create-my-own-package-from-a-compiled-source?rq=1

Comment: Use Google - I remember doing it for Ubuntu and then decided it wasn't worth the effort, especially for bash files - much easier to just zip up a package and have subdirectories that name where parts go if they are other than just a single place.  i.e., if some need to be put in /usr/sbin I name a subdir sbin inside the directory then zip it up that way.