# How do I create my own package from a compiled source?

Tags: packages

I have spent a few good hours compiling the latest `mono` for the Rasbperry Pi.

I wouldn't want to do this again, if it came to it. I tried cross compiling with `qemu` but I am still a noob with qemu.

So I endeavoured I have finally compiled it on the Pi, and got it working.(after 3 attempts)

How can I create a package with all dependencies, so I can just install it later?

Comment: It is may years since I did anything like this, and I found it an arcane process. You would be better to search on a Ubuntu or debian site for tutorials on building .deb files.

Comment: I tried checkinstall.... waited like 2 1/2 hours and then failed, with no proper indication of why. Somthing like `make install-revursive[ Error 1 ] `  ? :(

Comment: Keep checking if you are really determined to do this.  I remember that ultimately I found out how to do this for Ubuntu and did it but then decided it wasn't worth the effort.

Comment: Complimentary to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26108/how-to-package-shell-bash-files-for-apt-get?rq=1